# A Suitable Mission — The Professor's Revenge

Tags: code-golf, probability-theory, simulation

Summer Klerance turned in her term assignment for this [**challenge**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231585/a-suitable-mission#231761). Her professor was miffed (but also amused) when he overheard a disgruntled classmate of Summer's saying she got her answers by simulation rather than by the probabilistic methods covered in the course. Summer received a note to see the prof during his next office hours.

"OK, Miss Smarty-Pants*, I'll admit your problem was harder than any of the others I assigned. However, I'm not ready to give you full credit...Have a seat! If we order the goals by increasing difficulty of achievement, which you already, um, "found," we have:

> The Prof's *New* Order:
>
> **1** (Any) one complete suit **[7.7 hands]**
> **3** (Any) two complete suits [10.0 hands]
> **2** One given complete suit [11.6 hands]
> **5** (Any) three complete suits [12.4 hands]
> **4** Two given complete suits [14.0 hands]
> **6** Three given complete suits [15.4 hands]
> **7** The complete deck (all four suits) **[16.4 hands]**

**The Challenge**:

"I'd like you to modify your program. Keep track of the number of hands needed to see each of the seven goals as you deal, just as before. Let's define one ***trial*** as being completed on the hand when you've achieved *all seven goals*, i.e. a complete deck. The *order* in which you achieved each of the seven goals during a trial *may or may not match the New Order* I've shown you. To receive full credit for you term problem, I'd like you to tack a *single number* onto your output: **the percentage of total trials in which the order of goal achievement *exactly* matches the New Order**. And let's change our sample from 1 million deals to **20,000 trials** to ensure there is no partial trial at the end."

**Input:** None

**Output**: Same format as the [original challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231585/a-suitable-mission) with two changes: (a) the addition of the new percentage at the end of the output, and (b) a program run of exactly 20,000 trials, instead of the 1 million deals in the previous challenge.

**Rules** (revised):

(1) The results for the seven goals should be output in the **Old** Order (1-7) and not the New Order above. However, the percentage of interest is based on the **New Order** above, that of strictly increasing difficulty of achievement.

(2) Runs are no longer based on 1 million deals, but rather **20,000 completed trials** (roughly 330,000 deals).

(3) A tie resulting from achieving two or more goals on the same deal counts as a Yes, since it (also) fulfills the New Order requirement.

(4) The new number should come at the end of the output and needn't have a % sign.

(5) Show the result of *three* program runs, as in the original challenge. The data requested for each of the seven goals remains analogous to the original challenge: goal number; average number of hands needed in the 20,000 trials (rounded to one decimal place); minimum number of hands needed; and the maximum number of hands needed. The newly requested percentage should be at the end of the output.

(6) Code golf, so shortest <s>club</s> code in bytes wins.

---

*He didn't actually say that, but it was what he was thinking.

Comment: How are ties handled?  Ie, if two goals are reached at the same time, does that count as a failure run?  Sidenote: I like this challenge and the other, but I recommend avoiding finnicky output rules like (3) in the future.  They almost always make challenges less fun, and add little.

Comment: Points taken, thank you. I propose  I change the rules to (1) stipulate the percentage just has to  be at the end of the output without a % sign; (2) say ties count as fulfilling the New Order. Thoughts?

Comment: Rules have been revised

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>96</s> 78 bytes

```
%4‘ċⱮ4=13ḣḞƑ}¡S<
⁸;52Ẋḣ13¤Q$ç4$Ð¿çþ7H€¤§µ“Þ2ị’D¤ịṢƑ×³;@
2ȷ5¢€ZµÆmær1;Ṃ;Ṁ)µṪḢṭĖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AZsAZP9qZWxsef//JTTigJjEi@KxrjQ9MTPhuKPhuJ7GkX3CoVM8CuKBuDs1MuG6iuG4ozEzwqRRJMOnNCTDkMK/w6fDvjdI4oKswqTCp8K14oCcw54y4buL4oCZRMKk4buL4bmixpHDl8KzO0AKNci3MsKi4oKsWsK1w4Ztw6ZyMTvhuYI74bmAKcK14bmq4bii4bmtxJb/M8Ki4oKs/w)

A full program which is called as with no arguments and returns a list of lists of numbers. Each goal is represented in order as `[goal number, [mean, min, max]]` while the eighth list member is the percentage of trials matching the specified order. This is an extension of [my previous Jelly answer to the first part](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231599/42248). The TIO link runs three lots of 500 (5E2) trials rather than 20,000 (2E5).

Comment: I stipulated in the Rules that the percentage should be followed by the % sign. Do you want to add it, or should I just take it out?

Comment: Thanks, see my reply to Jonah.

Comment: @DjinTonic great. Have removed the %. Good challenges

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 170 bytes

```
≔Ｅ⁷⟦⟧εＦ×²⁰φ«≔Ｅε⁰ζ≔⁰δ≔⁰ηＷ№ζ⁰«≔⟦⟧θＦ¹³⊞θ‽⁻Ｅ⁵²μθ≧｜ΣＸ²θη≦⊕δ≔↨⁻⊖Ｘ²¦⁵³η⁸¹⁹²θＦΦ⁷‹§ζλ⎇﹪λ²⁼¹Σ…θ⊘⁺³λ›⊗№θ⁰λ§≔ζλδ»Ｆ⁷⊞§εκ§ζκ⊞υ∧¬⊙241536‹§ζＩκ§ζλ¹⁰⁰»Ｅε⪫⟦⊕κ⟦∕÷⁺×χΣι⊘ＬιＬιχ⌊ι⌈ι⟧⟧ ﹪%.1f∕ΣυＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVJdb9owFH0uv8KKNOla8qYkjHZTnyjso1PZUNc3xINHXGLh2CW2oXTqb8/8lQJanmzn3HPOPfeuatquFBVdN9aaryXM6BNcEbRYYoIYvh48qhbBA2@YhjInqMgxRn8HFydoRlDuwC8O3D87YHV@rf11X3PBEEyUlQZefFng6mGLJUFbj7sIosUQo7nVNWwJuqeyUg3MuLQ6iI5Kghrs8ThUuLfIcs/XtYEbbvZcs18tQb9tA3O1Zy2UAZ68HCvgVq5a1jBpWJV8945uqGZJdMreQEe60TDyEfSp@FziM/tfuTAO5bK8Y1rD2NzKij37toUDPrBW0vYAM1VZoUAQ5Mu/bC0VGoroenJYCTap1ZNP4DsVOy8tnJeh5/AfQd9aRr3MVNk/wv2P2W5DthGFYi@n@qnL10F0epVy7iFuoBtXfFKxCSEHkHU/ZAU/lYGxPEBWfixGw8vs/y4nVBvY4HMiEV0Xee4ZXwfzlju7aYt@KO6W4GQa4G0spnzHK@amZNIpZBBXsshjVNyzpojumFyb2j9h76q/hN0lyE2TN6HCnelzOi/d6mUoC8uUPMXBZO8@FI@uuyTtteyR1vp2rruue78T/wA) Link is to verbose version of code. Note: TIO link limited to 200 trials as 20,000 is too slow. +1 byte if you want to output a `%` sign. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ⁷⟦⟧ε
```

Start with an array of 7 empty lists of counts needed to reach the goal.

```
Ｆ×²⁰φ«
```

Loop 20,000 times.

```
≔Ｅε⁰ζ
```

Start with no goals found yet.

```
≔⁰δ
```

Start with no deals yet.

```
≔⁰η
```

Start with no cards yet.

```
Ｗ№ζ⁰«
```

Repeat until all goals have been found.

```
≔⟦⟧θＦ¹³⊞θ‽⁻Ｅ⁵²μθ
```

Deal 13 different cards at random.

```
≧｜ΣＸ²θη
```

Convert the cards into a bitmask and mark them as having been seen for this trial.

```
≦⊕δ
```

Increment the count for each trial.

```
≔↨⁻⊖Ｘ²¦⁵³η⁸¹⁹²θ
```

Find the suits for which all of the cards have now been seen.

```
ＦΦ⁷‹§ζλ⎇﹪λ²⁼¹Σ…θ⊘⁺³λ›⊗№θ⁰λ§≔ζλδ»
```

For each goal, mark it as satisfied if it is now but wasn't before. The flag is actually the count of deals for this trial so far.

```
Ｆ⁷⊞§εκ§ζκ
```

Push the counts to the lists.

```
⊞υ∧¬⊙241536‹§ζＩκ§ζλ¹⁰⁰»
```

Also keep track of whether this trial's results are in the desired order.

```
Ｅε⪫⟦⊕κ⟦∕÷⁺×χΣι⊘ＬιＬιχ⌊ι⌈ι⟧⟧
```

Format the averages as desired.

```
﹪%.1f∕ΣυＬυ
```

Format the percentage of trials in the desired order. Sample outputs (from TIO):

```
1 [7.6, 5, 14]  [7.8, 4, 16]  [7.8, 4, 14] 
2 [11.8, 6, 27] [11.9, 5, 33] [12.3, 5, 34]
3 [10.1, 6, 16] [10.0, 6, 17] [10.0, 6, 16]
4 [14.0, 8, 31] [14.4, 6, 33] [14.0, 7, 34]
5 [12.2, 8, 21] [12.6, 7, 22] [12.7, 7, 21]
6 [15.0, 8, 31] [16.1, 9, 35] [15.4, 7, 37]
7 [16.0, 8, 31] [17.2, 9, 35] [16.3, 9, 37]
  53.0          48.0          51.0
```